# Heroku application log

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

```
2022-01-14T13:53:27.307955+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    2022-01-14T13:53:27.307955+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    2022-01-14T13:53:27.307955+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    2022-01-14T13:53:27.307955+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    2022-01-14T13:53:27.307956+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
    2022-01-14T13:53:27.307956+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    2022-01-14T13:53:27.307956+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/commands/mute.js', '/app/index.js' ]
    2022-01-14T13:53:27.307957+00:00 app[Worker.1]: }
    2022-01-14T13:53:27.446922+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2022-01-14T13:53:27.529915+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed`
```

I've already added the `procfile` with `Worker node index.js`.

Someone said I have a problem with the mute.js file and here it is:

```js
const ms = require("ms");
module.exports = {
    name: "mute",
    description: "This mutes a member",
    execute(message, args) {
        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === "Mod");

        if (message.member.permissions.has("MUTE_MEMBERS")) {
            message.channel.send("you have the permission to mute members");
        } else {
            message.channel.send("you dont have the permission to mute members");
        }

        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (target) {
            let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "member");
            let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "Muted");

            let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);

            if (!args[1]) {
                memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
                memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
                message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted`);
                return;
            }
            memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
            memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
            message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted for ${ms(ms(args[1]))}`);

            setTimeout(function () {
                memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
                memberTarget.roles.add(mainRole.id);
            }, ms(args[1]));
        } else {
            message.channel.send("Cant find that member!");
        }
    },
};
```

I've never had any problems with my other bots when deploying them to Heroku. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Please include `index.js` and project folder structure.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is related, but this is not a valid `Procfile`: `Worker node index.js`. It should be `worker: node index.js` (lowercase `w`, and a colon after the process type).

Comment: @mswgen There is the index.js https://sourceb.in/Fk0OirxLaW and how would I include the whole project folder?